# iOS 10 - Swift 3 - Memory Leaks in spezializedDispatchQueue.init

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

When I analyze leaks in my iOS-App, the only ones I can find are caused by

```
spezializedDispatchQueue.init
```

and seems to point to weak and regular class variables.

I could not find anything helpful regarding this function.

[image: Leaks in Analyzer]

Does anyone have additional information, when this function is called, how to stop it from leaking and also: Should I care about it leaking some bytes?

Thanks